# Is my contact section correct semantically?

Tags: html

I work in a contact section of a website. Is my code correct semantically?

```
        <address>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://website.asd" hreflang="en" target="_blank">Website</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:somebody.someone@host.asd" hreflang="en" target="_blank">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul
        </address>
```

Comment: Correct in what sense? What about it isn't working for you?

Comment: See this: http://codepen.io/ssbalakumar/pen/uzDIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid and semantically appropriate? Yes, aside from the `</ul` missing it's closing angle bracket.

Correct? That's up to you to decide.

`address` elements can contain any flow content (except headings and sectioning content) related to the nearest `article` or `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will create an unordered (bulleted) list like the following:

- [Website](http://website.asd)
- [Contact Us](http://mailto:somebody.someone@host.asd)

Each with a hyperlink to the pages you have in the anchor's "href". It is 'correct' if that is what you were intending on doing.